# Plotly Interaction with DataTable in R Crosstalk

Tags: r, datatable, r-plotly, crosstalk

I am creating a flexdashboard (not shiny and knitted through markdown to create a static HTML) backed by the SharedData in the `crosstalk` package. I  have two types of data: `data_wide` used in the datatable that shows information about the `key` variable and `data_long` used in the plotly graph that will show a line graph of `score` for each `year` for each `key` variable.

However, my datatable and plotly graph does not seem to be interacting. In other words, when I select a row in the datatable, the plotly graph does not seem to highlight the line that represents that `key`.

Here is a mock code:

```
data_wide <- SharedData$new(data_wide, key = ~key)
data_long <- SharedData$new(data_long, key = ~key)

data_long %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~year, y = ~score, split = ~key, color = ~key, type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>% 
  highlight()

wide_data  %>% 
  datatable(style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%", rownames = F, escape = F, 
    options=list(deferRender=TRUE, scrollX = T))
```